# How to expand values in a dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For an example consider two dataframes A and B

Dataframe A:

```
Name1 | Col1 | Col2
------+------+-----
 A    |  1   | 2
 B    |  4   | 3
 C    |  6   | 8
```

and Dataframe B:

```
Name2 | Col3 | Col4
------+------+-----
 P    |  5   |  9
 Q    |  0   |  1
 R    |  2   |  7
```

and I wish to convert them into one dataframe like

New Dataframe:

```
Name1 | Col1 | Col2 | Name2 | Col3 | Col4
------+------+------+-------+------+------
 A    |  1   |  2   |  P    |  5   | 9
 A    |  1   |  2   |  Q    |  0   | 1
 A    |  1   |  2   |  R    |  2   | 7
 B    |  4   |  3   |  P    |  5   | 9
 B    |  4   |  3   |  Q    |  0   | 1
 B    |  4   |  3   |  R    |  2   | 7
 C    |  6   |  8   |  P    |  5   | 9
 C    |  6   |  8   |  Q    |  0   | 1
 C    |  6   |  8   |  R    |  2   | 7
```

How can I change it ?

Comment: What's the logic? Knowing that would be helpful.

Comment: Umm I need to do this thing to prepare upon my data that I am building up for my ML model @ShubhamSharma.

Comment: But why the keys are replicated three times only, there should be some logic here?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma the name actually represent github commit hashes and the files. It's quite complicated, but as I said, it is all gonna go in for a ML model

Comment: Ohhh Cartesian Product !!!! That's the word I was looking for. And I guess yes that's what I was exactly looking for. Thanks Man

Answer (score 2):

```
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
  Name1  Col1  Col2 Name2  Col3  Col4
0     A     1     2     P     5     9
1     A     1     2     Q     0     1
2     A     1     2     R     2     7
3     B     4     3     P     5     9
4     B     4     3     Q     0     1
5     B     4     3     R     2     7
6     C     6     8     P     5     9
7     C     6     8     Q     0     1
8     C     6     8     R     2     7
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this

```
A2 = A.copy()
B2 = B.copy()

DUMMY = 'dummy'
A2[DUMMY] = 1
B2[DUMMY] = 1

df = pd.merge(A2,B2)
df = df.loc[:,df.columns != DUMMY]
```

The reason it works is that merge joins on the common 'dummy' column on all values where they match. Given that dummy is constant, all the combinations match.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using data transformation with numpy, the basic idea is to duplicate rows in `df1` as many times as rows in `df2`.

```
n_cols = df1.shape[1]
vals = [np.hstack([np.repeat(df1.iloc[i,:], n_cols).values.reshape(-1, n_cols), df2.values]) 
        for i in range(len(df1))]
f = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(vals), columns=df1.columns.tolist() + df2.columns.tolist())

print(f)

  Name1 Col1 Col2 Name2 Col3 Col4
0     A    A    A     P    5    9
1     1    1    1     Q    0    1
2     2    2    2     R    2    7
3     B    B    B     P    5    9
4     4    4    4     Q    0    1
5     3    3    3     R    2    7
6     C    C    C     P    5    9
7     6    6    6     Q    0    1
8     8    8    8     R    2    7
```